# Does the ship saved by the Bio Integration Circuit get rolled on the turn the Circuit is used?

Tags: alien-frontiers

The Bio Integration Circuit says:

> Discard at the beginning of your turn to reclaim your ship docked at the Terraforming Station instead of returning it to the stock. Reclaimed ship goes to Maintenance Bay.

As it happens, you also pick up all of your dice/ships and roll them at the beginning of your turn. So do you get to roll and use the ship saved by the BIC as well? The rules are mum about the order of multiple effects at the beginning of your turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that happens on a normal turn is you pick up all of your ships, including any in the Maintenance Bay, except that a ship at the Terraforming Station goes to the stock.

In order for the Bio Integration Circuit card to move a ship from the Terraforming Station to the Maintenance Bay, it *must* happen before this phase, as otherwise your ship would no longer by at the Terraforming Station. Hence the sequence *must* be:

1. Play the card
2. Move the ship from the Terraforming Station to the Maintenance Bay
3. Pick up all of your ships, including any in the Maintenance Bay

So yes, you do get to use the reclaimed ship on the turn that you play the Bio Integration Circuit.